# Problem hiding Internet Explorer in WatiN, even when using Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin

This question is more of a follow-up to this one:
[Hiding Internet Explorer when WatiN is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555331/hiding-internet-explorer-when-watin-is-run)

Like the person who asked that original question, I also want to stop IE from being shown when my WatiN tests are running, but even when using this setting in a seemingly correct manner (code snippet below), it still ends up showing an empty IE window initially (although it does not show the test behavior/web page interaction).

Is it possible to stop the window from showing at all, or is this as good as it gets?

My helper method to create a new IE instance:

```
public static IE CreateNewBrowserInstance(string url = DefaultAppUrl)
    {
        Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
        Settings.Instance.AutoMoveMousePointerToTopLeft = false;
        Settings.Instance.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;

        return new IE(url, true);
    }
```

Comment: Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false; var ie = new IE(); ie.GoTo(url);

Comment: The code above didn't create any new IE window in my Win7 machine, with Watin 2.1.

Answer (score -1):

You can Hide window after initializing new IE instance

> browser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide);

Comment: My windows are already being hidden, but only after they pop up and annoy me.  The docs suggest that your answer would just minimize the window, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: OK, I gave it a try, and it didn't do anything to help.  I've got the same behavior as before.

Comment: This won't help because the window still flashes before you hide it.