# Hide a FileUpload dialog with Watin

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, dialog, watin, visible

I'm using a FileUpload with Watin and IE8 in C#. I don't want see anything on my screen. So, I use

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
```

and everything is hidden except my FileUpload dialog. This dialog appears on top even the instance of my browser is hidden.  Anyone have a suggestion to hide this ?

Thank you !

Comment: And I tried all I can see in these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555331/hiding-internet-explorer-when-watin-is-run
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095837/problem-hiding-internet-explorer-in-watin-even-when-using-settings-instance-mak

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help (not checked), When you initializing the Browser set this property:

```
browser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.ShowMinimized);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with another function ,you just set Url,save path and all works
add this in class

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 URLDownloadToFile(Int32 pCaller, string szURL, string szFileName, Int32 dwReserved, Int32 lpfnCB);
```

and this function

```
 int lwhdr = URLDownloadToFile(0, Link, FilePath, 0, 0);
```