# Check if browser closed manually

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, instance, watin

In visual studio 2010, working with c#;

I open a browser with:

```
private IE browser;

private void Set_Browser()
{
    string splashUrl = "google.com";
    browser= new IE(splashUrl);
}
```

If a user(person) closes the browser by accident, then my application will not be able to work anymore.

QUESTIONS:

1. So how do I check if a user closed the browser manually?
2. Can I unable a user from closing the browser by adding the browser to my
   application GUI as a control? *[using Windows Forms]*
3. -> How do I do that?

Last question related to this post [How to use watin with WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755747/how-to-use-watin-with-webbrowser-control) (2 years old, but no decent answer too)

EDIT: The solution in give URL seems to work. Problem is that if I try to send the WebBrowser.ActivateX.. as an object to other class. Then my browser = new IE(..) returns null. It does work when I instantiate it in the form class though. Any solutions?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60179/Web-Browser-in-C

Comment: ty for the link Sawan, there are mentioned some interesting features. However, noting related to WatiN is mentioned, as well as a way to implement it as a windows controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the process of internet explorer every x seconds and see if the browser is already running using this code:

```
    bool isRunning = false;
    foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("iexplore"))
            {
                    isRunning = true;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

You can use [this article](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1541.htm)

Or you can add a browser control to your application using [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60179/Web-Browser-in-C)

Comment: Does this also cover the case where just the relevant tab is closed and not the browser itself ?

Comment: Hmmm, it is not, required a further research :)

Comment: Ty for reply, but this is not sufficient enough. If I close the browser instantiated by WatiN and open a new IE myself manually, the program will crash. Because it cannot find the particular tab, even if there is an instance of IE running.

Comment: Regarding the articles, you can add an instance of the Webbrowser class as a control to your GUI. But I don't know (and not mentioned) how to add a IE (webbrowser) instace of WatiN to my control

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is hide the browser to avoid users closing it .. See this SO question.

[Hiding Internet Explorer when WatiN is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555331/hiding-internet-explorer-when-watin-is-run?rq=1)