# Watin works in background

Tags: web, automation, watin

I started using WaTin as web automation tools. My target is let WaTin run their tasks, when success (such as complete sign-in) it will show the results in textbox and datagrid. My question is does WaTin can work in the background? (Not open IE every time).

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding Internet Explorer when WatiN is run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555331/hiding-internet-explorer-when-watin-is-run)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the IE interface but it depends on the particular site you are working with. Most of the things can be done in the background but there are cases were you need to have the UI visible to calculate coordinates (like when you need to press a button inside a Flash movie) But to answer your specific question, yes Watin can work in the background. Take a look at the following method:

```
browser.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide);
```

browser is the Watin object.